# Is there a simpler type system with the practical utilities of CoC?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-systems

The Calculus of Constructions, as presented on the [Simpler, Easier](http://augustss.blogspot.com.br/2007/10/simpler-easier-in-recent-paper-simply.html) post, is a very simple type system which can be used as a programming language with all good properties you'd expect - type checking, correctness proofs, totality. Yet, given the similarity between Pi and Lam, and using Occam's Razor, I wonder: is there a system even simpler than CoC, with all those practical utilities?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be one?

Comment: I don't expect, but I think that, using Occam's Razor, when you have two very similar concepts in a system, it often means there is some non-obvious, more primitive concept that generalizes both. I just find this particular feature of CoC too oddly specific to be, among the space of possible systems, the simplest one that can be used for total functional programming and writing specifications as types. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: It's not CoC in the paper — it's the original version of MLTT with the impredicative universe. CoC only has impredicative `Prop`, which doesn't admit `Prop ∈ Prop`, but admits `(A : Prop) -> ... ∈ Prop`. Occam's Razor can produce only conjectures — it's not a proper argument.

Comment: @user3237465 woops okay, sorry.